# Grunt build: issue with concat task on a factory definition

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I am working on an application scaffolded using the angular-fullstack generator from yeoman.

So far we have been working without problem on the development version (`grunt serve` works without problem). Now we are ready to move to a production phase and so I've been trying to build a distribution using `grunt build`. We are using grunt's version 0.4.5.

Nevertheless the generated `app.js` file in `dist/.tmp/concat/app/` contains an error that is absent from the original file.

The tasks performed by the build are determined by the following part of `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'injector:less', 
'concurrent:dist',
'injector',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'autoprefixer',
'ngtemplates',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
[...]
```

Everything works fine until the build gets to `ngAnnotate`. At that time I get the following error:

```
error: couldn't process source due to parse error
```

The source of the parsing error rises from the following problem.

The original `app.js` contains the factory:

```
.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
return {
  // Add authorization token to headers
  request: function (config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
    }
    return config;
  },

  // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
  responseError: function(response) {
    if(response.status === 401) {
      $location.path('/login');
      // remove any stale tokens
      $cookieStore.remove('token');
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
    else {
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  }
};
})
```

But the corresponding piece of code generated by the first steps of the build looks like:

```
(function() {

function authInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $cookies, $location, Util) {
  return {
    // Add authorization token to headers
    request(config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($cookies.get('token') && Util.isSameOrigin(config.url)) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('token');
      }
      return config;
      },

   // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
   responseError(response) {
       if (response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
        // remove any stale tokens
        $cookies.remove('token');
       }
       return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}

angular.module('insuranceAppApp.auth')
  .factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);

})();
```

I've been trying for a while now to understand where the build is misbehaving. But I am an absolute beginner with grunt.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? 
Does anyone have an idea of what might be the source of the problem?